# Do tag descriptions/wikis edit suggestions no longer require two reviews?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

I tried to search for new and active topics on the subject here.

[As far as I know](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3901/14897), only mods can approve tag description/wiki suggestions by placing one vote.

By I just approved a suggestion for both a tag [description](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/48537) and [wiki](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/48536), no other votes were needed (I'm >25k).

Has something changed? Or is my understanding incorrect?

If something has changed, does it impact edit suggestions to normal posts (questions and answers)?

In case related: I created the tag hours before the suggestions.

Comment: It's not a bug: you're the tag's creator. Notice how your username is highlighted the same way OP's names are highlighted when they review edits on their posts.

Comment: @Jenayah: I *just* thought of that, added a note, and bam, your comment. Thanks. Dupe accepted.

Comment: It *might* be a different bug because the Community user is *supposed* to be the creator, followed by the human creator's user name. In addition, because you're [over 20K](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), you are a trusted user (much as you can edit without approval it makes sense that you can approve suggested edits on your own, owner or not).

Comment: Here's a 5K user approving a 39K user whom [created the tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/341627/revisions), also the *first* user is Community (unlike with your tag).

Comment: @Rob: Asked: [Why do I own this tag, and not Community ♦?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341936/392799)

Comment: Another inconsistency, I created the winter-bash-2019 tag and [I received the Taxonomist badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist?userid=282094) for it. ***But*** [click here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/winter-bash-2019/info) on "history" or "excerpt history" and Glorfindel is the creator, not Community or me. y --- Maybe this question (Bug) is closed prematurely.