# Why do I own this tag, and not Community ♦?

Tags: support, bug, tag-wiki, community-user

A follow-up from: [Do tag descriptions/wikis edit suggestions no longer require two reviews?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341934/392799)

From the dupe and comments, the tag creator should be Community ♦, why isn't it the case [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/73306/revisions)? Why do I *own* that tag and approve edits with a single vote?

Answer (score 3):

You're the owner of the tag wiki because you created the tag wiki *excerpt*.

As tag wiki and excerpt edits have to be submitted at the same time, once you submitted your excerpt edit without entering anything into the wiki box, it also submitted the blank wiki, so thus you own it.

This behavior is harder to find because it's inconsistent with what happens for suggested edits: no edit is submitted for that. But a blank wiki created by the Community user is still created for that (for diff purposes). The reason why no wiki edit is submitted is likely because it *is* submitted, but fails with an error of "this post is blank", but since the excerpt edit was allowed through, the system silently ignores that error. (See [my answer to the dupe you linked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341937/377214) for a more detailed explanation.)